как сделать так что бы после выполнения метода из одного модуля, переменные из второго модуля менялись
У меня есть переменная из класса PersonMenu
public string q3 = "Скушай хилку";
и я хочу что бы после выполнения метода Heart из класса Map
public void Heart(Hero obj)
        {

            Console.Clear();
            obj.SetHP(obj.GetMaxHP() / 10);
            obj.SetMaxHP(obj.GetMaxHP() + 10);

        }

значение переменной q3 менялось на "Квест выполнен", типо это квест
я все уже перепробовал и ничего не получается, подскажите пж

Во-первых, "Скушай хилку" - скорее, выглядит как действие, а "Квест выполнен" - это сообщение, констатация факта, и заменять первое вторым нелогично. Как длинное поменять на зелёное.
Во-вторых, так никто не делает. Почитай про принципы SOLID.
